# DHCP-policy for RRAS-VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn

I did set up a RRAS-VPN-Server for our network. It works almost fine. The only thing missing is that I want to create a policy on DHCP that can be used to communicate special options to the VPN-clients:
They should get some additional information for routing (option 121).

But I do not find a way to setup the policy-conditions that match the RRAS-Server's requests.

If I add a nonesense-condition like "MAC-Address NOT equal to DDDDDDDDDDDD", the options are communicated just fine to the VPN-Clients, but also to clients on the LAN.

What condition do I need to set for the VPN-Clients only?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom-line: I am pretty sure, this cannot be done. At least not with a static address-pool.

I used wireshark to check the communication between the RRAS-Server and the DHCP.
As far as I can see, there is nothing in there that can be used for a policy. Only the MAC-address could be an option, but it does not work unfortunately. Probably, because the RRAS ist just sending an "inform"-message to the DHCP, not a lease-request.